# Why is ContinueWith not run on a Task created with FromResult in a NUnit test

Tags: nunit

I have a class which I want to test, which (simplified) looks like  this:

```
public interface IHttpClient
{
    Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url);
}
class Downloader
{
    public string content = "";
    public void Download(IHttpClient client)
    {
        client.GetStringAsync("http://someurl").ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            content = t.Result;
        });
        // Do some other struff async
    }
}
```

The point is, that it uses ContinueWith to do something while the download is still running.

I have a unit test which looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task TestContinueWith()
    {
        var httpMock = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
        httpMock.Setup(p => p.GetStringAsync("http://someurl")).Returns(
            Task.FromResult("SomeContent")
            );
        Downloader d = new Downloader();
        d.Download(httpMock.Object);
        Assert.AreEqual("SomeContent", d.content);
    }
```

It fails because content is "".
But why? FromResult creates a finished task and ContinueWith should be executed?

Or will ContineWith not be run until some circumstances occurs? How can I fix this Unit Test?

Comment: All of this can be avoided by just making the test async as well and awaiting any task within. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nikosi Sorry, I have over-simplified the problem. I try to make it more complete now. The problem is, that the "ContinueWith" is not in the Unit test itself but in the class that is tested.

Comment: mixing sync and async is asking for trouble. Why cant `Downloader.Download` be made async?

Comment: @NIkosi Because it is an overwritten function from a class form a library which returns void. Actually it is the "Init" function from a FreshMvvm PageModel (https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm)

Comment: Understood. Ok this is seeming now more now of a design issue. There are work arounds but may be out of scope of the original question asked.